# reusable code in a single module

Tags: python

I am writing a python module that can handle several different tasks. Those tasks share certain pieces of codes as the following

```
if __name__ == '__main__:'
    task == sys.argv[1]
    if task =='task1':
        code block1
        code block2
        ...
    if task == 'task2':
        code block2
        ....
    if task == 'task3':
        some code
        code block1 
        ......
```

What is the best solution not to copy the code blocks in every task divisions without put them into functions as those code blocks will produce many local variables.

update: I am thinking of something in Matlab, placing abc.m line into your code with run the block of code in abc.m. I wonder if there is a way to run the block of code saved somewhere in the module, other than a function (I prefer to keep all my functions with as less side effect as possible)

Comment: Why is it a problem if the functions generate lots of local variables? Do you mean you need the variables outside of the function scope? You can `return` them.

Comment: Why would you not want to put them into functions? That's literally the point of them

Comment: The obvious choice are, well, functions. Why don't you want to use functions there? Show us a more concrete example so we can understand your problem better.

Comment: Unclear: "without putting them into functions" -- why? "[because] those code blocks will produce many local variables" -- huh?

Comment: ^ You should take it as a hint you're doing this wrong that within 6 seconds 4 people were confused by your idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, maybe function is the only possible way to do it. Then the functions need to return a long list of variables. I personally like to write my functions in a more ''functional'' way.

Comment: If your functions are producing lots of output variables then they are poorly organized.  Each function should do one specific thing. Functions can call other functions, so you can use that to reduce the number of variables you have to pass around.  So you would probably have one top-level function that picks the correct task, then a function for each task, then the function for each task will call zero or more other functions (each of which may call zero or more other functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have said, the best solution is probably using functions. If you need to pass lots of variables from one Function to another you could also use this approach:

```
if __name__ == '__main__:'
    task == sys.argv[1]

    if task == 'task3':
        some code

    if task =='task1' or task == 'task3':
        code block1

    if task == 'task2':
        code block2
```

But I highly recommend thinking about another solution. Your code blocks should represent certain tasks that are working independent of each other and then: functions! The solution I presented gets ugly fast and it will be difficult to keep track of what code block provides which variables.